# me dice que la variable num1 no esta definida

Tags: javascript

hola saludos no me reconoce la variable num1
y no se que hacer eh probado de todo y no se por que
me dice que num1 no esta definido..

```
function numero() {
  var num;
  do {
    num = prompt("introduce 5 numeros");
  } while (isNaN(num) || num.length != 5)
}
numero();

function numero2() {
  var num1 = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
  }
}
numero2();
document.write(num1.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

Answer (score 3):

La variable num1 la creaste dentro de la función numero2() por lo tanto solo existe dentro de esa funcion. No está definida porque estás intentando acceder a ella desde fuera de numero2().
Para entenderlo mejor:

```
var ejemplo1 = 1;

function alertExample(){
  var ejemplo2 = 2;
  alert(ejemplo1);//Funciona
  alert(ejemplo2);//Funciona
}

alertExample();//Primero alerta 1 y luego 2
alert(ejemplo1);//Funciona alerta 1
alert(ejemplo2);//No funciona, no puede acceder para alertar 2
```

A la variable ejemplo2 solo puedo acceder llamando a la función alertExample(), mientras que la variable ejemplo1 se puede acceder desde su mismo nivel y cualquiera dentro de este nivel.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas definiendo a num1 como una variable local.
Debes definir a num1 como una función global. Ademas si quieres usar al metodo sort, tienes que definir a num1 como un array.

Esta seria mi solucion:

```html
var num1 = [];

function numero2() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    num1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1));
  }
}
numero2();
document.write(num1.sort((a, b) => a - b));
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas tratando de usar la variable `num1` fuera de su alcance definido.

Entiendo que quizás al declarar `num1` como `var` esperabas que sea global. Pero si vas a la documentación de [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) podrás notar lo siguiente:

> El ámbito de una variable declarada con la palabra reservada var es su contexto de ejecución en curso, que puede ser la función que la contiene o, para las variables declaradas **afuera de cualquier función**, un **ámbito global.** (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description)

Esto quiere decir que tu variable `num1` no es global, ya que la declaraste dentro de una función.

Aquí tienes 2 opciones.

1. Declarala fuera de la función `numero2()`

```javascript
var num1;
function numero2() {
  num1 = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
  }
}
numero2();
console.log(num1); // Está definida
```

2. La otra opción es devolver `num1` en la función

```javascript
function numero2() {
  var num1 = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
  }
  return num1;
}
var num1 = numero2();
console.log(num1); // Está definida
```

Comment: ahora me dice que console.log(num1.sort((a, b) => a - b);  me dice que sort() no es una function....

Comment: Eso pasa porque `sort()` es una funcion presente solo en arreglos. `num1` es simplemente una variable numérica. Puedes ver mas sobre `sort` aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score -1):

```
var num = 0;
function numero() {
  do {
    num = prompt("introduce 5 numeros");
  } while (isNaN(num) || num.length != 5)
}
numero();

var num1 = [];

function numero2() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    num1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
  }
  num1.sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
numero2();
document.write(`<h4><b><br>${num1} numeros ordenados de menor a mayor </b></h4><br>${num} numeros que eh jugado `);
```

esto era lo que queria hacer gracias todos saludos..